# Variable is not being updated

Tags: c++, variables, updating

So, I'm designing an RPG game and my battle system is not working.
I'm fairly new but I have a good understanding of what I have here for the most part. Whenever I run the battle system, the 'eHp' and 'hp' variables are not being updated.

```
hit = rand() % atk + 1 + (rand() % 3 + 1);
            diff = hit - OppD;
            if (diff > 0)
                eHp = eHp - diff;
            if (eHp <= 0)
                break;
            OppHit = rand() % OppA + 1;
            OppDif = OppHit - def;
            hp = hp - OppDif;
            if (hp <= 0)
                break;
```

This is inside a switch statement within a while loop. The display for the health points is in the while loop before the switch statement. The switch statement is used to decide which attack the player decides to use.
If you need to see more code. Just say how much you need to see and I will update it.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check with a debugger if the variable values (of atk, hit, OppD ...) are something sane, if the `if`-conditions are fulfilled and the code inside executed, and if there is something unexplainable (like if-conditions not executed altough the condition is true, or wrong subtraction results etc.)?

Comment: @deviantfan No I was never taught how to use the debugger

Comment: Neither was I (taught by someone else how to use a debugger), but that´s something so important that you should learn it yourself, and as soon as possible. Google and just trying on some programs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your block of code to this block of code and paste the output in your question if looking at the output hasn't already solved it for you.

```
hit = rand() % atk + 1 + (rand() % 3 + 1);
diff = hit - OppD;

std::cout << "hit: " << hit << "\ndiff:" << diff << "\neHP: " << eHp << std::endl;

if (diff > 0) eHp = eHp - diff;
if (eHp <= 0) break;

OppHit = rand() % OppA + 1;
OppDif = OppHit - def;

std::cout << "OppHit: " << OppHit << "\nOppDif: " << OppDif << "\nhp: " << hp << std::endl;

hp = hp - OppDif;

if (hp <= 0) break;
```

Comment: Changing to this block of code did not change anything also it doesn't execute the cout statement

Comment: @ShadowWesley77 I hope it gave you a bunch of output.

Comment: @Johnathan Mee No it didn't give me any more output than it already does

Comment: @ShadowWesley77 Sounds like you found your problem. This block of code is never executed. You'll have to look at the conditionals surrounding this block. One of them is your problem.

Comment: turns out the switch statement condition was in the char data type, but i had the cases as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the switch statement condition was in the char data type, but i had the cases as the int data type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @dove But i figured out my problem. Is there a way to delete this question?

Comment: @ShadowWesley77 You should see this at the bottom of your question: "share|edit|close|delete|flag" just click "delete"